# Can I match on a search string and show the lines above it in IOS?

Tags: cisco-ios

For example, I have a MAC address which i know is the MAC address on one of the interfaces. However when I search to what interface the MAC address belongs, it does not show me to what interface it belongs as this is on a separate line.

When using grep to go through a router config I can use **grep -5 [MAC ADDRESS]** to show 5 lines above and 5 lines below the line on which the search string is found. How ever MAC addresses are not in the running config, so is this possible?

A sort of workaround I use now is use **sh interaces | begin [MAC ADDRESS]**

If I know the interface below I know what interface the MAC address belongs to.

So is there an equivalent of **grep -5 [MAC ADDRESS]**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this awnser from another forum:

I figured it out, but you need an IOS version that has IOS.sh:

```
term shell
sh ru | grep -u H.H.H | tail 10
```

The -u flag will show all of the lines above the mac address you're searching and then the tail command will just show the last ten lines of that output. You can substitute "10" with however many lines you want.

**Prerequisites for Cisco IOS.sh**

• Cisco IOS Release 15.1(4)M, 15.1(2)S, and later releases.

• Cisco IOS.sh must be configured and enabled to use the Cisco IOS.sh features and functions on yourrouter.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/netmgmt/configuration/guide/Convert/IOS_Shell/nm_ios_shell.pdf

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: I have accepted my awnser

Answer (score 2):

According to the following Cisco documentation there is no such equivalent grep-5 command.  The pipe command does support regular expressions to help filter the output.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/fundamentals/configuration/15_sy/fundamentals-15-sy-book/cf-cli-search.html

The following command could make the output more readable.  (Alternation)

```
show interfaces | include Gig|0000.0000.0000


Switch#show interfaces | in Gig|000c.5e48.0801
GigabitEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet0/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
  Hardware is iGbE, address is 000c.5e48.0801 (bia 000c.5e48.0801)
GigabitEthernet0/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet0/3 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet1/0 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet1/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet1/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
GigabitEthernet1/3 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
```

Some switch IOS code will list the MAC addresses of its interfaces with the following.

```
show mac address-table
```

OR

```
show mac-address-table
```

Comment: I figured as much as I did a lot of googling. Thank for the tips.

Comment: @frankguthrie, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if you're happy with it.

Comment: The | section command is a fantastic alternative to | include when it's available.  For example: show run | section aaa will show you the aaa new-model command AND all of it's sub-commands AND any other line in the config that contains aaa.  Very handy.